# SplitPipe for a FormControl property does not work

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-pipe

I am trying to split the input values submitted to the form based on the commas between them. Here is an example,

TS FILE

```
export class FoodComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  private food;

  amount = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

  constructor(public serviceFood: FoodService, fb: FormatBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      amount: this.amount
    });
  };

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.loadAll();
  }
}
```

for the table in HTML FILE

```
<td>{{food.amount}}</td>
```

every time the user input the amount they had on the day, the values are shown like this:

4.3,5.2,2.3

all of the inputs are rendered in one cell. I want to split them and either print them in different rows in one cell or multiple cells in multiple rows.

recently I came across pipes and have installed angular-pipes. imported SplitePipe into my local ts file. but when I make the following changes, nothing comes up:

```
<td>{{food.amount | split(',')}}</td>
```

also tried the split with Hello World, my page does not come up:

```
<td>{{'Hello World' | split}}</td>
```

I am searching all over the solutions. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error do you get on console

Comment: @Ashok console error:     [Script Loader] ReferenceError: "require is not defined"
    <anonymous> scripts.bundle.js line 25 > eval:1
    exports addScript.js:20
    524 testcheck.js:1
    Webpack 5
addScript.js:8
    log addScript.js:8
    exports addScript.js:25
    524 testcheck.js:1
    Webpack 5
[Script Loader] ReferenceError: "filter is not defined"
    <anonymous> scripts.bundle.js line 25 > eval:2
    exports addScript.js:20
    523 splitFunction.js:1
    Webpack 5

Comment: looks like you are missing imports.Have you imported Splitpipe?

Comment: just found the answer. I was missing imports in the app.module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to pass parameters into pipes is slightly different then regular functions. You don't use parentheses and commas, but instead you use a `:` before each parameter, like this:

`<td>{{ food.amount | split : ',' }}</td>`

Comment: tried this, doesn't work for me. {{food.amount}} works but as soon as I introduce | to the argument, gives me the error above in console.

Comment: Have you added `SplitPipe` to the declarations array in your `NgModule`?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing importing in the app.module. For the common pipes, I needed to `import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';` in app.module and declare in imports. Also, importing them in the local components.

For split, I needed to declare in my `NgModule`. Both @Ashok and @Mendy responded too.